# DropDownList и SqlDataReader присвоение значения

Tags: ado.net, c#

Не могу понять почему не задать значение в ddl.SelectedIndex, тип переменных столбца к которому обращаюсь smallint, пишет "Заданное приведение является недопустимым":

```
     SqlDataReader rdr_SQL = cmd_SQL.ExecuteReader();
            StringBuilder strResult = new StringBuilder("");
            while (rdr_SQL.Read())
            {
                tb_wp.Text += (Int16)rdr_SQL[1];
                tb_netname.Text = (string)rdr_SQL[2];
                try {tb_ports.Text += (Int16)rdr_SQL[10];} catch{ };
                try{tb_gnezds.Text += (Int16)rdr_SQL[12];} catch{ };
                try{tb_vlan.Text += (Int16)rdr_SQL[13];} catch{ };
                try{tb_ip.Text = (string)rdr_SQL[14];} catch{ };
                tb_username.Text = (string)rdr_SQL[15];
                try {tb_date.Text += (DateTime)rdr_SQL[16]; }catch { };
                try {tb_adv.Text = (string)rdr_SQL[17]; } catch { };
            ddl_workshops.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[3];
            try { ddl_departaments.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[4]; }catch { };
            try {ddl_rooms.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[5];}catch { };
            try {ddl_tels.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[6];}catch { };
            try {ddl_servers.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[7];}catch { };
            try {ddl_boxs.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[8];}catch { };
            try {ddl_switchs.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[9];}catch { };
            try { ddl_path_panels.SelectedIndex = (Int16)rdr_SQL[11];}catch { };
        }
        rdr_SQL.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, вместо (Int16) используйте

```
Convert.ToInt16(rdr_SQL[1].ToString())
```

, а еще лучше

```
Int16.TryParse(rdr_SQL[1].ToString())
```

Comment: Первый вариант компилит, но выдает ошибку как добирался до ddl:
ddl_workshops.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(rdr_SQL[3].ToString());
Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Второй вариант даже не компилит:
ddl_workshops.SelectedIndex = Int16.TryParse(rdr_SQL[3].ToString());
Ни одна из перегрузок метода "TryParse" не принимает "1" аргументов

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то rdr_sql.GetInt16(1);

Comment: Так что то и не удалось, сделал через доп. переменные, напрямую не хочет присваивать значения. Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 2):

Про второй вариант, я забыл указать, что первый параметр, это то что вы ходите преобразовать, а второй куда записать значение. Сам метод TryParse возвращает true, в случае успешного преобразования или false, в другом случае. Правильно работать с методом так:

```
Int16 id=0;
if (Int16.TryParse("ваше значение", out id))
{
   //преобразовалось, значение находится в переменной id
}
else
{
   //не удалось преобразовать.
}
```

Посмотрите в дебагире какое находится значение в переменной, которую вы пытаетесь преобразовать, возможно, там находится не то, что вы ожидаете.